# Portable MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb

I have been wondering if it is possible to have a portable MongoDB instance.

My goal is making a full Javascript + HTML5 application, and store data in a **/data** folder, and each *collection* would be a .json file, but hardcoding a literal **database** would be certainly reinventing the wheel (or steel).

I googled some Javascript-made JSON databases as a reference, but my eyes **shine** on BSON data formats.

Is that possible?
Or better, am I missing another mind-breaking technology that would fit my needs?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi there, I don't know for mongoDB, but for CouchDB there's one browser implementation: http://pouchdb.com/

Comment: You can also try local storage via HTML 5 - http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: There isn't a "portable" MongoDB instance available.  Using local storage would be a good approach if you want to keep everything contained in the JS application.  There's an interesting open source project for querying JS objects with MongoDB syntax ([Ask.js on Github](https://github.com/lodr/askjs)), but I'm not sure how helpful that would be for your use case.  It could be nifty to hook that up to local storage for a mock MongoDB, but the layers might add significant performance overhead.

Comment: Have you ever tried dockers?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Disclaimer: I just came across this and haven't tried it yet.
MongloDB (https://github.com/Monglo/MongloDB) looks interesting.  From my quick look it appears to be a MongoDB look alike interface that makes it easy to back with local storage or a cache and AJAX to a server side store.  But as I say I have not tried it yet.  The joys of random github finds.

Comment: A M A Z I N G.
That's what I'm talking about! Thank you, dude!

Comment: Most pleased I could help.  If you do something interesting with it I would love to read the blog post you write :)

Comment: Sorry for commenting on such an old thread, but it would be great if this gets hosted out of Github, in a safe website for people with restricted access to Github, Chocolatey and all of these managers.

Answer (score 12):

I created [NeDB](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb) - a pure Javascript database implementing the MongoDB API. It can be used as a Node.js module and in the browser and supports persistence.

It also supports indexes which make it much faster than databases who don't (e.g. TaffyDB and it seems to be the case for MongloDB as well)